# When to access Static Button in ListView EmptyItemTemplate and ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a button in both the ItemTemplate and EmptyDatatTemplate of my Listview that I would like to dynamicly change the PostBackURL on depending on the data that is used to fill the listview. i know the I can use code similare to

```
tbEditAbout = (TextBox)lvCharacters.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("tbEditAbout");
```

to get access to the button but what I dont know is what On method to be making the call in so that everytime the page is loaded via a full load or an AJAX postback I can update the value of the button's PostBackURL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OnItemDataBound event

protected void Expenses_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {

       TextBox tbEditAbout = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbEditAbout");
    }
}
```